# contact trigger efficient way

Tags: trigger

I've to update field on Account which shows total count of Contacts associated with Account (after insertion and deletion of contact)

```
I've written it and it seems to be working fine
```

But I'm finding in all similar sceenario, I always have to make use of subqueries. just wondering what other way exist or is there some other efficient way for this so that I can write triggers without making 'much'use of subqueries

```
trigger ContactBulkupDateCount on Contact (after insert, after delete) {

   Set<id> AccIds = new Set<id>();

   if(!trigger.isDelete)
  { 
     For (Contact c : trigger.new)
       AccIds.add(c.AccountID);
  }

 else
  { 
     For (Contact c : trigger.old)
       AccIds.add(c.AccountID);
  }

    list<Account> AccList = [select id, Count_of_Contacts__c , (select id from contacts) from Account where id = : AccIds];

    Map<Account, integer> mpAcctoContactCount  = New Map<Account, integer>(); 

    For (Account acc : AccList) 
      { 
        acc.Count_of_Contacts__c  =acc.Contacts.size();

      }

    update acclist;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
trigger updateContactCount on Contact (after insert, after update, after delete, after undelete) {
    Map<Id, Account> accounts = new Map<Id, Account>();
    if(Trigger.old != null) {
        for(Contact record: Trigger.old) {
            accounts.put(record.AccountId, new Account(Id=record.AccountId, Count_of_Contacts__c=0));
        }
    }
    if(Trigger.new != null) {
        for(Contact record: Trigger.new) {
            accounts.put(record.AccountId, new Account(Id=record.AccountId, Count_of_Contacts__c=0));
        }
    }
    accounts.remove(null);
    for(AggregateResult record:[SELECT Count(Id) Records, AccountId AccountId FROM Contact WHERE AccountId IN :accounts.keySet() GROUP BY AccountId]) {
        accounts.get((Id)record.get('AccountId')).Count_of_Contacts__c = (Decimal)record.get('Records');
    }
    update accounts.values();
}
```

This trigger correctly updates the counter for all accounts, even if the contact switches from one account to another, is deleted and subsequently undeleted, or if there are no contacts remaining on the account.

Please note that if you expect more than 50,000 contacts to appear in the query (you have large accounts), you may need to offload this into a batchable class and use the more traditional counting method. A truly optimized trigger would only actually fire on insert, delete or undelete, and only updates where the account ID actually changes. Also, no error checking is performed in this example, but that is probably not a concern unless you think you may have validation rules that could cause the accounts to not update correctly.

Comment: Thanks this helps!.  I really forgot to consider scenario , what would happen , if contact changes Account.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely you can. You need to query all the contacts related to the accounts affected in the trigger, iterate through the contacts and by using a map, count the number of contacts that have the same `AccountId`. Something like this:

```
trigger ContactBulkupDateCount on Contact (after insert, after delete) 
{
    Set <Id> accIds = new Set <Id> ();

    for (Contact c : trigger.isDelete ? trigger.old : trigger.new)
    {
        accIds.add(c.AccountId);
    }

    Map <Id, Integer> accountContactsCount = new Map <Id, Integer> ();

    for (Contact c : [SELECT AccountId FROM Contact WHERE AccountId IN :accIds])
    {
        if (accountContactsCount.get(c.AccountId) == null)
        {
            accountContactsCount.put(c.AccountId, 0);
        }

        accountContactsCount.put(c.AccountId, accountContactsCount.get(c.AccountId) + 1);
    }

    List <Account> accountsToUpdate = new List <Account> ();

    for (Id accountId : accountContactsCount.keySet())
    {
        Account account = new Account (Id = accountId);
        account.Count_of_Contacts__c = accountContactsCount.get(accountId);
        accountsToUpdate.add(account);
    }

    update accountsToUpdate;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bachovski. Your solution is as much helpful as of sfdcfox. I can mark just one as correct solution

Comment: Do I get an upvote at least? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use query like this to retrieve size of related contacts

```
List<Contact> con = [select id from Contact where Account.id = : AccIds]
```